# How to draw and rotate image along with text in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem with drawing and rotating image on my canvas. Basically, my approach is to create the wheel of fortune which allows customization based on the prizes in form of array. The data in this array makes up the segment inside the wheel based on the number of indexes.

The data is very simple. It is just a simple JSON object like this

```
var prizes = [
{product:"Axe FX", img: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"},
{product:"Musicman JPX", img: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"},
{product:"Ibanez JEM777V", img: "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"}
];
```

This data is used to create the segments inside the wheel. So I want to place the text which is currently working like a charm for me.

When drawing the wheel, I separate into two main functions. One to draw the wheel and another to draw the segments inside the wheel.

```
var drawPartial = function(key, lastAngle, angle) {
var value = prizes[key].product;

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.fillStyle = segColors[key];
ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, lastAngle, angle);
ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
ctx.rotate((lastAngle+angle) / 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillText(value.substr(0,20), size / 2 + 20, 0);
ctx.restore();

ctx.restore();
}

var draw = function() {
var len = prizes.length;
var currentAngle = outCurrentAngle;
var lastAngle = currentAngle;

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.font = "1.4em Arial";

for(var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    var angle = (Math.PI*2) * (i/len) + currentAngle;
    drawPartial(i-1, lastAngle, angle);
    lastAngle = angle;
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size/7, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
// ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
// ctx.stroke();
}
```

With the code above, I just simple call the draw() function and the wheel and all segments will be created accordingly. However, I want to draw the image in each segment but I don't know to make it work. This is the modification of drawPartial() for rendering images along with text

```
var drawPartial = function(key, lastAngle, angle) {
var value = prizes[key].product;

var img = new Image();
img.src = prizes[key].img;
img.onload = function() { 

    ctx.save();
    ctx.drawImage(img,centerX,centerY);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(centerX,centerY);
    ctx.rotate((lastAngle+angle) / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(img,centerX,centerY);

    ctx.restore();
    ctx.restore();


}

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.fillStyle = segColors[key];
ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, size, lastAngle, angle);
ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
ctx.rotate((lastAngle+angle) / 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillText(value.substr(0,20), size / 2 + 20, 0);
ctx.restore();

ctx.restore();
}
```

You can see that I add image and its src based on the prizes object which should be called in each iteration called by the main draw() function but it never renders any image in any segment.

What I want is. In each iteration of drawPartial(), I want the image to be placed in the segment along with the text and rotated according to the angle.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

In your `img.onload` function you are "double translating" your centerX & centerY.

`ctx.translate(centerX,centerY)` will move the canvas's [0,0] origin to [centerX,centerY].

So when you `ctx.drawImage(img,centerX,centerY)` to draw your image, you are really double moving.

As a result your image is really being drawn at `[ centerX*2, centerY*2 ]`.

**A additional thought: Preload your images**

It's best to preload all your images. That way if an image fails to load you can take reparative action before you begin drawing your wheel.

Here is how to preload all of your images so they are available when you need to draw them onto your Wheel:

```js
// your incoming JSON 
var prizesJSON='[{"product":"Axe FX","img":"https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"},{"product":"Musicman JPX","img":"https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"},{"product":"Ibanez JEM777V","img":"https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png"}]';

// the JSON converted to a JS array of objects
var prizes=JSON.parse(prizesJSON);

// preload all images
var imageURLs=[];  
var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
// add prize images into the image preloader
for(var i=0;i<prizes.length;i++){
  imageURLs.push(prizes[i].img);
}
startLoadingAllImages(imagesAreNowLoaded);
//
function startLoadingAllImages(callback){
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function(){ 
      imagesOK++; 
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}
// 
function imagesAreNowLoaded(){
  // add the img objects to your prizes array objects
  for(var i=0;i<prizes.length;i++){
    prizes[i].imageObject=imgs[i];
    // just testing (add the img to the DOM)
    document.body.appendChild(imgs[i]);
  }
  // All images are fully loaded
  // So draw your wheel now!
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
```

```html
<h4>Testing: (1) Preload all images, (2) Add imgs to DOM</h4>
```

**I had this laying around...**

I see you already have code to draw your Wheel, but I had this code in my code archive so I offer it here just in case it has some use for you.

Here is an example of how to draw a "Wheel of Fortune" with each blade containing a prize image and text. The techniques used include:

- `context.translate` to set the rotation point to the center of the wheel.
- `context.rotate` to rotate each blade to its desired angle.
- `context.textAlign` & `context.textBaseline` to draw centered text.
- `context.globalAlpha` to lighten each blades color so the black text has good contrast.

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;
var bladeCount=10;
var sweep=PI2/bladeCount;
var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var radius=130;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png";
function start(){
    for(var i=0;i<bladeCount;i++){
        drawBlade(img,'House'+i,cx,cy,radius,sweep*i,sweep);
    }    
}

function drawBlade(img,text,cx,cy,radius,angle,arcsweep){
    // save the context state 
    ctx.save();
    // rotate the canvas to this blade's angle
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    // draw the blade wedge
    ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.arc(0,0,radius,0,arcsweep);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    // fill the blade, but keep the color light
    // so the black text has good contrast
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.30;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    // draw the text
    ctx.rotate(PI/2+sweep/2);
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='middle';
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillText(text,0,-radius+50);
    // draw the img 
    // (resize to 32x32 so be sure orig img is square)
    ctx.drawImage(img,-16,-radius+10,32,32);
    // restore the context to its original state
    ctx.restore();
}

function randomColor(){ 
    return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```